# Can weighted sampling be more efficient than sampling?

Tags: importance-sampling

Suppose that you have a normal distribution D with density f, which you sample. An estimator produces the maximum likelihood normal distribution $G_n$ given n samples.

On the other hand you could sample from a normal distribution with density f to the power k. And you could weight those samples by f to the power 1-k. An estimator produces the maximum likelihood distribution $H_n$ given n samples.

Is there a k for which H converges to D faster than G?

Is there a better sampling method than G?  Another idea is to consider when our original sampling algorithm would have produced two samples that are very close in value. Then why not omit the second one and increase the weight of the first one?

Comment: Apologies for the poor markup, I don't have access to a keyboard for a while. Edits appreciated.

Comment: Any (positive) power of a Normal density is a Normal density (with a different SD), which implies your procedure accomplishes nothing.

Comment: @whuber my guess is that things get worse when k is not 1 since you're increasing the sampling density in precisely the places that you're reducing the sample weights. However my question is more general:. I'm asking whether there exists any weighted  sampling process that beats regular sampling.

Comment: (I only provided the sequence H because it was my first attempt)

Comment: Now that I think more about it it seems like when k is larger than 1, the mean converges faster, whereas when it's less than 1 the variance converges faster?

Comment: That cannot possibly be true, because the change you are making is inessential.  Sampling from the power of the density is identical to sampling from the original density and rescaling the results relative to the mean.  You will get *exactly* the same rates of convergence, merely measured on a different scale.

Comment: I see your point. So maybe they're not different rates of convergence, by different ks give different numbers of samples to achieve a particular amount of error in the mean and variance.  Anyway, like I said this question is about whether there exists any algorithm.